# How to retrieve rows where third or any letter after the third is a specific letter using LIKE operator in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm a beginner in SQL and I use MySQL database.
I have a table called "employees".
How to retrieve only those employees whose third or any letter after the third is "r"?
I have to use the LIKE operator.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE last_name LIKE "__r%"
```

, but I think it only retrieves those employees who have "r" as the third letter in their last name.

Comment: Single quotes instead of double for literals

Comment: not in MySQL @JoelCoehoorn

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Almost there. You just need another wildcard before the `r` (the wildcard can also match 0 characters).

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE last_name LIKE '__%r%'
```

Or, you could use [`Substring()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE Substring(last_name, 3) LIKE '%r%'
```

Either way, the performance will not generally be great, as you'll have to evaluate every row in the table (even if you only want a few), and indexes won't be very helpful.

Comment: Great, that's pretty intuitive but I haven't thought of it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from customer
WHERE last_name LIKE "__%r%"
```